# Why does scheme find a variable defined with "define" and not "let"

Tags: scheme, scope

So here's a question about scheme variable binds.  Let's say I have the following function:

```
(define undefinedTest (lambda (y) (list x y)))
```

This will warn of x being an unbound variable when run in Guile-Scheme 2.0.3.  If I then execute the following statement

```
> (let ((x 'something)) (undefinedTest 'else))
```

I will get an error and the option to debug it.  However if I execute the following statements:

```
> (define x 'something)
> (undefinedTest 'else)
```

I get the expected answer of (something else).  Why is scheme able to bind x when it is defined at the top-level, but not when it is bound by let.  Is this because when the function is defined it is also defined at the top-level, and so when scheme go to search its nearest enclosing environment, the let environment is not actually "enclosing" as it still starts its search at the "top-level"?

Comment: Ensure the title aligns with the "real question" in the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scheme uses lexical scoping, not dynamic scoping. So the `x` the `undefinedTest` sees is the `x` that is lexically visible from that function, which in this case, as you've already noted, is the top-level scope.

Answer (score 1):

When `undefinedTest` was defined, it enclosed the environment in which it was defined; given that it was defined at the top level, it will only "see" its formal parameter `y` and the global environment - and the global environment doesn't contain `x` at that point. It's like that because Scheme is lexically scoped.

I tested the code in the question in Racket and the first line fails with the error: `expand: unbound identifier in module in: x` - meaning that it's not even a valid definition as interpreted by Racket.

The same example would work in a language with dynamic scoping, Scheme uses lexical scoping (a.k.a. static scoping.)

Answer (score 1):

Lexical scope is a core feature of Scheme.  With lexical scoping, you can always tell which bindings are visible to a function, because they are those visible at the point where the function is defined.  Dynamic scoping, in contrast, has a tendency to create surprises which can be hard to foresee and equally difficult to debug.